# Writing a file in binary or bytecode

Tags: java

I am storing large amounts of information inside of text files that are written via java. I have two questions relating to this:

1. Is there any efficiency boost to writing in binary or bytecode over Strings?
2. What would I use to write the data type into a file.

I already have a setup based around Strings, but I want to compare and at least know how to write the file in bytecode or binary.

When I read in the file, it will be translated into Strings again, but according to my reasearch if I write the file straight into bytecode it removes the added process on both ends of translating between Strings and code both for writing the file and for reading it.

---

cHao has a good point about just using Strings anyway, but I am still interested in the how if how to write varied data types in the file.

In other words, can I still use the FileReader and BufferedReader to read and translate back to Strings, or is there another thing to use. Also using a BinaryWriter, is it still just the FileWriter class that I use???

Comment: My first thought is, you'd be doubling the amount of storage required (unless you're writing a lot of non-ASCII text).  UTF-8 requires 1 byte per char for ASCII text, but if you wrote a raw string it'd be 2 bytes per.

Comment: Also, you don't write a string "in bytecode", unless you're talking about serialization.  Even then, it's not called that.  Bytecode is JVM instructions.

Comment: @cHao. Always good to learn sth new :P. So that leaves it up to straight binary then?

Comment: Unless you have some really good reason, i'd stick to regular old text.  And in most cases, skipping encoding/decoding isn't that good a reason; both can be pretty freaking fast.  Only bother with writing bytes if you've tried and *seen* that byte<->char conversions are a bottleneck.  Java's pretty much always going to do some bit twiddling to turn bytes into chars; you're probably not going to be saving enough to justify the added complexity.

Comment: Sounds reasonable... and To be honest, in one programming class the teacher used a text file of the entire book "A tale of two cities", read it in, removed all the duplicate words and printed it to the console and all told it was a few seconds on a crap machine.... still interested in the "how" though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write it in "binary", and you want to save space, why not just zip it using the jdk? Meets all your requirements.

Comment: I am not so interested in the space aspect so much, I am interested in reducing the amount of processing power required to read back in in the interest of speed, space is secondary or even off the map as I have no real concern for it.

Comment: Then your question is vague; if you're writing string data, and reading string data, any translation step will take more time. At some file size, the amount of data will become the gating factor, and it will be faster to compress/decompress. Reading and writing data is not a CPU-intensive task, but at some point it will be faster overall to reduce the quantity of data being read/written.

Comment: Java always translates the string to another form anyway I am pretty sure, and I know that String characters = 2 bytes which doubles space and if I am not mistaken the result of this is that it takes twice as long to read. But then again it does sounds as if I am mistaken... :P, thanks for the help, I am going to wait a bit longer and see if an answer comes in that solves the second portion of my question.

Comment: Bytecode, as already mentioned, is a specific term with specific meaning, that doesn't seem related to your question as worded. What do you mean, it "translates the string to another form"? What form does it translate a string to? What various datatypes are you writing that ends up being a string again? If it's a string, it's not another datatype, it's a string.

Comment: Specifically, a DataOutputStream writes a stream into what I believe is bytecode though I am not totally sure on that, and it should store in that way in the file that I am writing. When I read it back in (because the file is just storage on the disk) then can I use BufferedReader to read it back as a String. In other words I deal with strings in the program, but theoretically I could have bytecode in the file. make more sense?

Comment: Please stop saying "bytecode" for this--bytecode is JVM opcodes. In any case, everything I said still stands: there's an inflection point at which the size of a text file will cause reading/writing to take more time than compression/uncompression. Java strings are unicode by default: even if you write it as 8-bit ASCII, there's still a conversion process.

Comment: All-right, I think I get it. Thanks for your patience in explaining to a brick wall :P.

Comment: No sweat :) Sometimes we're the brick, sometimes we're the... um... other thing.